# Symfony validation: range between two numbers, OR a value

Tags: symfony, validation

I would like to validate a number to be between 10 and 20, or 30 and 40 or equal to 99.

I could imagine the code to be something similar to this, but it does not work:

In Entity\NameOfFile.php:

```
/*
 * @Assert\Range(
 *   min=10,
 *   max=20
 * )
 *
 * @Assert\Range(
 *  min=30,
 *  max=40
 * )
 *
 * @Assert\IdenticalTo(value = 99)
 */
 private $myVariable;
```

Or maybe something similar to this:

```
 /*
  * @Assert\Choice({
  *  Range({min = 10, max = 20}),
  *  Range({min = 10, max = 20}), 
  *  99
  * )}
  */
  private $myVariable;
```

I also added min and max messages.

In the first option, apparently only the first Assert is taken into consideration and the second one is ignored. The second option, does not work at all.

Ps: Please, a solution without Regex

EDIT: 
Following the advice of M Khalid Juanid, the code looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getmyVariable() in 10..20 or this.getmyVariable() in 30..40 or this.getmyVariable() == 99",
 *     message="Your error message", groups{"groupA"}
 * )
*private $myVariable;
 */

  ***
if($appendForm->isValid(array($groupA))
{
***  
}
```

It works fine, but only when the validation is not assigned to groupA. How can, the validation be assigned to a group, in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`@Assert\Expression`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) for your mulitple criteria

```
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.checkRange()",
 *     message="Your error message"
 * )
 */
class YourEntityName
{
    public function checkRange(){
        if(
            ($this->yourPorperty >= 10 && $this->yourPorperty <= 20)
            || ($this->yourPorperty >= 30 && $this->yourPorperty <= 40)
            || ($this->yourPorperty == 90)
        ){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

> As per docs *The [expression](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) option is the expression that must return true in order for validation to pass*

Even more simpler according to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html#numeric-operators)

```
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getYourPorperty() in 10..20 or this.getYourPorperty() in 30..40 or this.getYourPorperty() == 90",
 *     message="Your error message"
 * )
 */
```

Comment: You need `this.getYourPorperty()` here instead of `this.yourPorperty`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It works fine. But how can I assign this validation to a group?  I put the new code on the post.

Comment: @BabyWebnaster in `FooFormType.php` https://gist.github.com/tulik/99f6b752035d0adbbf6556a0d1de5004

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom validation constraint. To create one you can refer to the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/validation/custom_constraint.html

You will have to put all your constraints in the `validate` function of the Validator class.

Answer (score 0):

Since Symfony 5.1, there is a new validator that can check if at least one of several constraints is met.
[AtLeastOneOf](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/AtLeastOneOf.html)

```
 /**
 * @Assert\AtLeastOneOf({
 *      @Assert\Range(
 *          min=10,
 *          max=20
 *      ),
 *      @Assert\Range(
 *          min=30,
 *          max=40
 *      ),
 *      @Assert\IdenticalTo(value = 99)
 * })
 */
private $myVariable;
```